# Python percent calculation 0E-14 as results

Tags: python, python-3.x

My percent calculation print as result always: `0E-14` instead of `0.000037488`

**Code:**

```
import decimal

firstvalue = 3.0233  # (%)
amount = 0.00310000
firstcal = decimal.Decimal(firstvalue)
firstcalresult = (firstcal / 100) * amount
```

> **Result is 0.00009372230000, it works fine**

```
percentage = 40

feepercent = firstcalresult
feepercentresult = (percentage / 100) * feepercent
```

feepercent = 0.00009372230000

> **Result is 0E-14, but must be 0.000037488**

Why works on first calculation and on second not? i have tried it also with `decimal.Decimal` but same result. Any one ideas?

Comment: Can you provide all values so we can reproduce the exact result?

Comment: how is amount defined?

Comment: `print((40 / 100) * 0.00009372230000)` gives `3.748892e-05` which is `0.00003748892` So i dont see any issue here other than a possible coding issue

Comment: Cannot reproduce. You didn't provide `firstvalue`, but if I set `firstcalresult=0.00009372230000`, I eventually get `3.748892e-05` which is equal to the expected result. | I suspect `0E-14` mean you probably executed the second part of the code a lot, as the exponent is -14... that's e9 times less than expected.

Comment: Also, can you verify that you run on python3 and not python2? py3: `40 / 100 => 0.4` while in py2 `40 / 100 => 0`. I suspect that you run in py2 which means that you should declare percentage as float (`40.0`) or cast it `(float(percentage)/100)`

Comment: Updated with values, Yes Python 3.

Comment: based on your update this code will produce a typeError  `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'decimal.Decimal' and 'float'`

Comment: And creating a decimal from a float is not the way to go. `print(decimal.Decimal(3.0233))` gives you `3.02329999999999987636556397774256765842437744140625`.

Comment: i dont get any errors. I just dont understand why the first calculation works but the second not and they have the same amount of zeros before

Comment: Noone can reproduce your problem. This can't be the code you're running.

Comment: sure its copy and paste, i get in my log file for result `feepercentresult: 0E-14`

Comment: What do you mean with "in my log file"? Didn't you do a `print(feepercentresult)` to look at the value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the full solution without any error:

```
import decimal

firstvalue = 3.0233  # (%)
amount = 0.00310000
firstcal = decimal.Decimal(firstvalue)
firstcalresult = (firstcal / 100) * decimal.Decimal(amount)
percentage = 40
feepercent = firstcalresult
feepercentresult = decimal.Decimal(percentage / 100) * feepercent
print(decimal.Decimal(feepercentresult))
```

The solution you get is:

```
0.00003748891999999999923054522233
```

Answer (score 0):

**Solved:**

```
percentage = decimal.Decimal(40.0000)
```

gives me the correct results.

Comment: Yes. Check my solution

Comment: Not only this, you have to add decimal.Decimal near ```amount``` too.

Comment: just `decimal.Decimal` dont work, tried yesterday as first thing. it must be `40.0000` not just `40`

Comment: Try out my solution. You will get the ouput. Just run my solution. I have inserted decimal.Decimal while calculation.